# MANOVA with repeated measures in R, error

Tags: r, manova

I conducted listening experiment in which 16 participants had to rate the audio stimuli along 5 scales representing an emotion (sad, tender, neutral, happy and aggressive). Each audio stimulus was synthesized in order to represent a particular emotion. Participants had to move 5 sliders each of which corresponded to one of the 5 emotions.

The sliders range was [0,10] but participants were only informed about the extremities of the sliders (not at all - very much).
There was not a force choice, therefore potentially each audio stimulus could be rated with all the scales (e.g. sad = 0.1, tender = 2.5, neutral = 2., happy = 8.3, aggressive = 1.7).

There were 40 stimuli, each stimulus was repeated twice, for a total of 80 trials.

To analyze the data I want to use a MANOVA with repeated measures (in R).
For this purpose I use the audio stimulus as independent variable having 40 levels, while the 5 responses as dependent variables. Since each individual has been measured twice, I include a within-subjects factor for trial number.

I want to demonstrate that the created stimuli were actually correctly classified in the corresponding emotion. For example I expect that happy sounds result in happy ratings by participants and that these happy ratings are greater than the other 4 responses.

I studied the R documentation and examples, but I encountered the following error while adapting those examples to my case:

```
model.emotions<-lm(cbind(Sad,Tender,Neutral,Happy,Aggressive) ~ Trial,data=scrd)
idata<-data.frame(scrd$Trial_number)
aov.emotions<-anova(model.emotions,idata=idata, idesign=~Trial, type="III")

> aov.emotions<-anova(model.emotions,idata=idata, idesign=~Trial, type="III")
Error in cbind(M, X) : number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

I am not fully sure of the above formula, since I am not an expert in R. Can you please correct them showing the correct R code?

The .csv table with all the data can be downloaded here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3288659/Results_data_listening_Test.csv

In addition I was not able to find any post hoc test to apply to the result of the MANOVA in case of a significant main effect. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Before proceeding I have a few clarification questions and comments. One problem I see is that you have duplicated trial numbers for each participant. Thus, although each participant completed 80 trials, you have 1-40 twice. A trial number should be a unique identifier. Also, is it the case that each of the forty sounds you have represents a separate manipulation or emotion (which is what you are testing if you included 40 levels of the IV) or are they grouped into the 5 emotions you mentioned?

Comment: Dear Marcus, thanks a lot for replying. Yes, I agree the trial number should be a unique identifier. I changed accordingly the table, and it can be downloaded at the same address: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3288659/Results_data_listening_Test.csv . Regarding your second question, I want to use 40 levels since I used 40 different files generated in 40 different ways. However, I am open to other suggestions, even if the first analysis I would like to conduct is with 40 levels.

Comment: I don't believe your desired analysis will work. You have only 16 participants and require 39 degrees of freedom to estimate an effect for each audio clip. I would suggest you will have to group your audio clips in some meaningful way. As to your difficulty with the syntax, I haven't used lm for this purpose before. I generally use [John Fox's car package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car//index.html) for applications like this.

Comment: Dear Marcus, then I should group the audio clips by type of trial. This will produce a factor with 20 levels. The resulting table can be dowloaded here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3288659/Results_data_listening_Test_Grouped.csv I added the factor Trial_type, that now will become my independent variable. Can you help me with the R code? Actually I studied the car package, but with no luck. Any suggestion is very appreciated.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.psycho.uni-duesseldorf.de/aap/projects/gpower/reference/reference_manual_09.html#t1) under MANOVA for the calculation of degrees of freedom. Audio category = Groups = k = 20 in your design. You have far too few participants to estimate this model. Unless you can drastically reduce the levels of your IV, MANOVA will be untenable for this question.

Comment: No, I cannot reduce to less than 20 levels. So which analysis should I use instead?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4356/discussion-between-marcus-morrisey-and-luca)